# Pointer scope in linked list function cpp

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

```
struct Entry {
    std::string name, phone;
    Entry *next;
};

Entry * getNewEntry() {
    std::cout << "Enter name (RETURN to quit): ";
    std::string name;
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    if (name == "") return NULL;
    Entry *newOne = new Entry; //allocates a new entry struct obj in the heap
    newOne->name = name;
    std::cout << "Enter phone number: ";
    std::string number;
    std::getline(std::cin, number);
    newOne->phone = number;
    newOne->next = NULL; //in this function pointer to next entry is NULL
    return newOne;
}

void prepend(Entry *ent, Entry *first) {
    ent->next = first;
    *first = *ent;
}

Entry * buildAddressBook() {
    Entry *listHead = NULL;
    while (true) {
        Entry *newOne = getNewEntry();
        if (!newOne) break;
        prepend(newOne, listHead);
    }
    return listHead;
}
```

Why does not work this line in `prepend()`?:

```
*first = *ent;
```

I know I could pass first by reference and get it to work, but if I am referencing first and setting that equal to the struct that ent points to why doesn't this work? Even if the pointer vars are passed by value they still point to the same struct?

Comment: What do you mean with "not work"?  The code as you have it will crash with a NULL pointer dereference because `listHead` is NULL in the first call to `prepend` (so `first` will be NULL in the function).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What `*first = *ent` does is copy the data byte for byte pointed at by `ent` to the location pointed at by `first`, which in your example will be NULL, and probably cause a seg fault.

What you want is first to be either a reference to a pointer (*&) or a pointer to a pointer (**), so you can change the pointer in the outside function.

For your purposes I suggest reference as it will be easier to read.

So prepend should be (notice I've removed the derefs on the equal line):

```
void prepend(Entry *ent, Entry *&first) {
    ent->next = first;
    first = ent;
}
```

Comment: thanks, just our of curiosity, the pointer to a pointer works because i dont have to dereference null? so i would be dereferencing **first which would get me the address to first and then setting that = to ent which is also a pointer?

Comment: @crypt3c Yes. A pointer is just a variable that holds a location in memory. A pointer to a pointer is a variable that holds the location in memory of a pointer. So you can use that to do things to and with the pointed to pointer, for instance set it.

Answer (score 1):

*Pointer means the value at address = Pointer. As pointer is currently pointing to garbage you will get a seg fault.

You cannot first dereference "first" because first is pointing to a location in memory that is most probably not of your program's own.